# Get middle screen pixel (color) in C# (full screen game)?

Tags: c#, colors, fullscreen, pixel, intptr

I'm running a full screen game and I'm trying to find out the color of the middle pixel. The code I'm using however, seems to only work with windowed applications/games/etc. This is my code:

```
public static Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y) 
{
    IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
    Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
            (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
            (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);

    return color;
}
```

I'm getting the middle screen pixel like this:

```
int ScreenWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int ScreenHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

So how can I make this code compatible with full screen games?
It gives me an ARGB value of `A = 255, R = 0, G = 0, B = 0`, even though I'm 100% positive that the middle screen pixel is RED.

Comment: For one, you have the RGB arguments in reverse order (BGR).

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173287/getting-a-pixel-from-the-screen-in-a-full-screen-game-c-windows

Comment: My apologies, but I'm fairly desperate to solve this issue as fast as possible. I will delete the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's about:

```
//using System.Windows.Forms;
public static Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y) 
{
    Bitmap snapshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using(Graphics gph = Graphics.FromImage(snapshot))  
    {
        gph.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }

    return snapshot.GetPixel(x, y);
}
```

Then:

```
Color middleScreenPixelColor = GetPixelColor(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width/2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height/2);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I'm doing this for a game and this method is put into a while loop with 30ms delay between each cycle so basically every 30ms I'm taking a snapshot which kind of makes the game lag (and my whole computer). Isn't there another way?